# How to match a pattern, delete the pattern and also the next and the previous line on Solaris 10

Tags: text-processing, sed, solaris

How can I match a pattern, delete the pattern and also the next and the previous line on Solaris 10?
I'm hiting the wall because Solaris does not come with GNU sed.
Given the following file content:

```
    LinearFile(3F007F106F3B, FDN, 29, 20)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F40, XXX, 29, 1)
    {
        LinearRec(1, 12345)
    }
    LinearFile(3F007F106F3C, SMS, 176, 20)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F4F, ECCP, 15, 10)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F40, XXX, 29, 1)
    {
      LinearRec(1, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    }
    LinearFile(3F007F106F42, SMSP, 43, 3)
    BinaryFile(3F007F106F43, SMSS, 2)
    LinearRec(1, 12345)
```

I would like to remove the block that contain:

```
    {
      LinearRec(1, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    }
```

The file would be:

```
LinearFile(3F007F106F3B, FDN, 29, 20)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F40, XXX, 29, 1)
    {
        LinearRec(1, 12345)
    }
    LinearFile(3F007F106F3C, SMS, 176, 20)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F4F, ECCP, 15, 10)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F40, XXX, 29, 1)
    LinearFile(3F007F106F42, SMSP, 43, 3)
    BinaryFile(3F007F106F43, SMSS, 2)
    LinearRec(1, 12345)
```

To delete the next line I issued the following:

```
sed -e '/LinearRec(1\,\ FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)/{n;d;}' file.txt
```

What about the line that matchs and the previous line?

Maybe it can be achieved by using ed or vi?
Thx!

Comment: The only restriction is not to use `sed`? `grep` and `awk` are fine?

Comment: No, you can use any tool. There's no restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `perl` approach (assuming your file is small enough to load into memory):

```
perl -0pe 's/.+?\n.*?LinearRec\(1, F{58}\).*?\n.*?\n//' file
```

The `-0` makes `perl` slurp the entire file, and the `-p` tells it to print each input line after applying the script given by `-e`. The script itself matches 58 `F`s and the surrounding two lines and removes them.

Comment: I changed a little to direct change the file. perl -0pi -e...

Comment: There's any way to change F{58} to *F* like @mikeserv suggestion?

Comment: @Jonathan sure, you can use the same format as Mike did: `perl -0pe 's/.+?\n.*?LinearRec\(1, *FF*\).*?\n.*?\n//' file`

Answer (score 5):

Here's an `ed` script:

```
ed <<\!
e file.txt
/LinearRec(1, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
-1,+1d
w newfile.txt
!
```

It writes the output to file `newfile.txt`.

---

The "global" repeated version of this is

```
ed <<\!
e file.txt
g/LinearRec(1, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)/-1,+1d
w newfile.txt
!
```

Comment: you should do those more often. i like `ed`.

Comment: After some time I managed to do with VI, but the problem is that if the delete does not work, vi will not quit the file.
vi -c ':g/LinearRec(1, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)/-1,+1 d|:x' file.txt
This also happens using ed?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. It works for me, but I'm not on solaris. I looked at the [online man pages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/index.html) for `ed` and they seem to match what I am using.

Comment: Sorry to not be more specific. If I run the vi -c on a file that there's no LineaRec(...), vi will open the file, go to the last line and will not quit. The save and quit, ":x" will not run.

Comment: Try separating the commands into 2 -c options: `vi -c ':g/..../-1,+1d' -c ':x' file.txt`.

Comment: It worked! Thx for your suggestion @mueh
Awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

```sh
sed -ne'$p;N;/^ *{ *\n *LinearRec(1, *FF*) *$/n;/\n/P;D' <in >out
```

That gets `sed` a one-line look-ahead, and then only `P`rints to output any lines which don't fit your series, because it jumps one more and dumps the buffer when it matches the first two lines of it.

Comment: sed on solaris does not have -i, there's any way to change the file directly without it?

Comment: @Jonathan - neither `perl`'s `-i` nor GNU `sed`'s `-i` have ever directly modified a file, and are actually writing your edits to a temporary file that they then `mv` over the target file at end of input. You could easily do the same with `sed ... <in >out && mv out in` or in Solaris 10's `/bin/sh` *(which ought to be Bourne)* `sed ... <<IN >infile\n\`cat <infile\`\nIN\n` where the `\n` stand here in the comment for actual newlines.